# Terraform AWS auto_scaling_policy p95

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have an auto-scaled group that has detailed monitoring enabled. I should be able to create an autoscaling policy that allows me to scale based on the p95 CPUUtilization, just like I see in the graphs in Cloudwatch. However, I can find no real example of what that would look like.

I have several examples of what fails:

```
resource aws_autoscaling_policy asg_scaling {
  name                      = "${local.component}-scaling-policy"
  adjustment_type           = "ChangeInCapacity"
  policy_type               = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name    = "${aws_autoscaling_group.asg.name}"
  estimated_instance_warmup = 300

  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "p95.CPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 40.0
  }
}
```

fails with

```
* aws_autoscaling_policy.asg_scaling: Error putting scaling policy: ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value 'p95.CPUUtilization' at 'targetTrackingConfiguration.predefinedMetricSpecification.predefinedMetricType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [ASGAverageCPUUtilization, ASGAverageNetworkOut, ASGAverageNetworkIn, ALBRequestCountPerTarget]
    status code: 400, request id: 83ecfae0-94fe-11e8-8c0a-112a070bfa5d
```

and another try looks like

```
resource aws_autoscaling_policy asg_scaling {
  name                      = "${local.component}-scaling-policy"
  adjustment_type           = "ChangeInCapacity"
  policy_type               = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name    = "${aws_autoscaling_group.asg.name}"
  estimated_instance_warmup = 300

  target_tracking_configuration {
    customized_metric_specification {
      metric_dimension {
        name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
        value = "${aws_autoscaling_group.asg.name}"
      }

      metric_name = "CPUUtilization"
      namespace   = "EC2"
      statistic   = "p95"
    }

    target_value = 40.0
  }
}
```

fails with

```
* aws_autoscaling_policy.asg_scaling: Error putting scaling policy: ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: Value 'p95' at 'targetTrackingConfiguration.customizedMetricSpecification.statistic' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [Maximum, SampleCount, Sum, Minimum, Average]
    status code: 400, request id: e05440ac-94fb-11e8-abba-43f2e6549e03
```

Does anyone know how to actually use p95 with the "TargetTrackingScaling" policy?

Comment: Hi, hope this throws some light to your issue. If you want to use the predefined_metric_specifications there are only 4 provided by AWS : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_PredefinedMetricSpecification.html However, this is not a valid answer to your question (that's why I commented)

Comment: In Target tacking scaling policy, cloud provider has control according to the given minimum and maximum threshold.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zvjm.png)